# White space below the footer of my website on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS and have finally created my new website. The site works fine on my laptop and PC, but when I open it on my phone, there is this huge white space covering half my screen in portrait mode. It's perfectly fine in landscape mode.

I want my website to be completely zoomed in when opened in portrait mode, so that you can swipe/scroll to navigate on the site and get rid of the white space. Basically, at the moment, when the site is opened, it zooms out to show 100% of the site, but I only want it to show whatever fits the mobile screen in portrait mode. Hope my question is clear. I've been searching for an answer for over 3 hours now. Please help me guys :(

My css: https://pastebin.com/AeHyczJh
My HTML: https://pastebin.com/N5jV8yqY

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Affordable and professional web design">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web design, affordable web design, professional web design">
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">

        <header>

            <div class="container">

                <img src="images/final.png" width="162" height="200" alt="logo" id="logo"/>

                <nav>
                  <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Registration</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="./regist-team/regist-team.html">Team</a>
                          <a href="./regist-ind/regist-ind.html">Individual</a> 
                          <a href="soon.html""soon.html">Coach a team</a>
                          <a href="soon.html">Manage a team</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">KWSA Women's Soccer League</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="soon.html" class="dropbtn-2">Match Schedule</a>
                          <a href="soon.html" class="dropbtn-2">Practice Schedule</a>
                          <a href="soon.html">Pitch Locations</a>
                          <a href="soon.html">Team Kits</a>
                          <a href="soon.html" class="dropbtn-2">Top Scorers</a>
                        </div>  

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Sponsors</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="soon.html">Sponsors of KWSL</a>
                          <a href="soon.html">Sponsor a team</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Info</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="soon.html">Rules</a>
                          <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="carpool.html">The Carpool Program</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </header>

        <section id="main_content">



                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WSd0HZVh5pE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                <div id="main_text">
                    <h1></h1>
                    <p></p>
                </div>



        </section>

        <footer>

            <div class="foot-container">

                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KWFL2017/"><img src="images/fb.png" class="social_fb"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png" class="social_youtube"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/insta.png" class="social_insta"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/mail.png" class="social_mail"></a>


            </div>


        </footer>



    </div>  
</body>
</html>

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'YourFontName'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url(''); /*URL to font*/
}

@charset "utf-8";

@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      html{
        max-height: 5px;
      }

}

body{
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: url(images/field.jpg) no-repeat 0 -200px;
}



h1,
p{
    margin: 0;
}

#wrap{

}

.container{

    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}


header{
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    min-width: 1300px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}


#logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    margin: auto;
}

header li{
  float:center;
  display:inline;
  padding: 0 70px 0 0px;

}

nav{
    float: right;
}

header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
}



header a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;

}


iframe{
    position: static;
    top: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    float:right;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 100px black;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 200px 20px 0px 0px;
}



#main_content{
    position: static;
    min-height: 700px;
    min-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#main_content h1{
    position: absolute;
    left: -135px;
    top: 165px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:"Bauhaus 93"; 
    font-size: 50px;
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 150px;

}

#main_content p{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 410px;
    top: 275px;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 700ms ease; 
    border: black 1px solid;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px black;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgba(208,208,208,0.8);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color:black;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

li a, .dropbtn-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown2:hover .dropbtn-2 {

}


.dropdown-content-2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1A3C60;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-2 a {
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content-2 a:hover {background-color:rgba(56,97,159,0.46)}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    margin-top: -47px;
}

li.dropdown2 {
    display: inline-block;
}


#FAQ{
    position: static;
    background: url(images/faq_bg.png) center no-repeat ;
    min-width: 1300px;
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

#FAQ h1{
    padding-top: 75px;
    color: #e4e3e3;
    font-family:"Bauhaus 93"; 
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 390px;


}

#FAQ ul p{
    text-align: left;
    color: #e4e3e3;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#FAQ ul{
    text-align: left;
    color: #e4e3e3;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.social_fb{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(168,168,168,0.7);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.social_fb:hover{
    background: #3b5998;
}

.social_youtube{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 520px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(168,168,168,0.7);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.social_youtube:hover{
    background: #bb0000;
}

.social_insta{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 540px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(168,168,168,0.7);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.social_insta:hover{
    background: #8a3ab9;
}

.social_mail{
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 560px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(168,168,168,0.7);
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.social_mail:hover{
    background: #e4a805;
}


#carpool{
    position: static;
    background: url(images/faq_bg.png) center no-repeat ;
    min-width: 1300px;
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
    height: 100%;
}

#carpool h1{
    padding-top: 75px;
    color: #e4e3e3;
    font-family:"Bauhaus 93"; 
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 390px;

}

#carpool ul p{
    text-align: left;
    color: #e4e3e3;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#carpool ul{
    text-align: left;
    color: #e4e3e3;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    left: 400px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
}


#soon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 550px;
    top: 300px;
}
```

Comment: From the code you've provided, it doesn't seem that the page is designed to be responsive to mobile devices. For example, the CSS contains minimum width definitions of 1300px and some elements are absolutely positioned to places that would be off screen on smaller devices. You may want to read a little about responsive design, particularly about fluid layouts, designing with percentages, and how to use media queries. That being said, it's difficult to tell exactly what you're seeing. Is it possible to include screen shots or a link to the page, for reference?

Comment: As a *very* rough example, I've removed some of the absolute positioning and pixel-based layout in [this demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/y9jw7h4v/embedded/result/). See if it performs any differently on your phone.

Comment: These might be informative: [Responsive vs. Adaptive Layout Design](https://www.weareconvoy.com/2013/12/responsive-vs-adaptive-layout-design/) and [MDN on Responsive Design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Progressive/Responsive)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'll definitely read up the links you've sent me. I'm attaching this imgur link of the screenshot from my phone. 
http://i.imgur.com/KvzL3ba.jpg